# iOS Exchange Contacts Properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, exchange-server

When adding an exchange account to an iOS device, what information is being stored from the exchange server? Specifically, I am trying to get the contact id from a specific contact if this type of information is retained. This way I do not have to query the exchange server for the information needed in the app we are developing. I'm assuming that iOS needs this information to keep track of changes, but how do I get this information?

Comment: did you ever find the answer ?